# why does this single quoted string get interpreted when it's inside of a command substitution

Tags: shell, sh

Compare these two lines of shell script:

```
printf '%s' 's/./\\&/g'                    #1, s/./\\&/g
printf '%s' `printf '%s' 's/./\\&/g'`      #2, s/./\&/g
```

My question is: why does the single-quoted double backslashes get interpreted as a single backslash for the second line of script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

```
printf '%s' `printf '%s' 's/./\\&/g'`
```

The expression inside backticks returns `s/./\\&/g` as in the first expression, without single quotes, so you get

```
printf '%s' s/./\\&/g
```

The first backslash escapes the second one, so it prints `s/./\&/g`.

Comment: May I ask you one more related question, why does this prints &&&, not abc  ? 

        echo "\`echo 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g'\`"

Comment: @pdg you should ask another question.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait and ask it in another hour. Thanks anyway.