# double backslashes of sed single-quoted command inside command substitutions get translated to a single backslash

Tags: shell, sed, sh, backticks, command-substitution

```
printf '%s' 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g'                        #1, \a\b\c
printf '%s' "`printf '%s' 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g'`"        #2, &&&
```

The expression inside the second backticks returns `\a\b\c`, and we have `printf '%s' "\a\b\c"`, so it should print `\a\b\c`.
My question is: why does the second script print `&&&` ?

note:
I can get the second script work (prints `\a\b\c`) by prepending each backslash with another backslash, but I don't know why it's needed.

One related question:
[why does this single quoted string get interpreted when it's inside of a command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788936/why-does-this-single-quoted-string-get-interpreted-when-its-inside-of-a-command)

Comment: `printf '%s' "$(printf '%s' 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g')"` works fine btw

Comment: @anubhava wow, really it is. So backsticks have some odd side-effects I guess.

Comment: Yes,  backticks suck,  there is really no reason to ever use them. Look here for more info regarding your problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Yes use of back-ticks is discouraged now

Comment: @123 Thanks for your link, very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example to show difference between back-tick and `$(cmd)` command substitutions.

> When the old-style backquoted form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by "$", "`", or "\".
>   The first backticks not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the "$(COMMAND)" form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

So take a look your example, I used `echo` instead of `printf`:

```
kent$  echo 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g'
\a\b\c

kent$  echo -E "`echo 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g'`"
&&&

kent$  echo -E "$(echo 'abc' | sed 's/./\\&/g')"                    
\a\b\c
```

You can see, the back-tick command substitution made your `\\` as single `\`, thus together with the followed `&` it became `\&` (literal `&`)

Note that I used `echo -E` in order to disable the interpretation of backslash escapes so that the `\a\b\c` could be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

Because on the second line :

you are saying:

```
printf '%s' 'abc' -> 'abc'
```

Then replace:

```
'abc'| sed 's/./\\&g' -> &&&

The s mean substitute
. mean one character
\\& by a char &
g mean multiple occurrence on the line
```

So you are saying:

Replace in abc each char by & multiple time on the same line

Explanation of `\\\&` :

```
Two backslashes become a single backslash in the shell which then in sed escapes the forward slash which is the middle delimiter.

\\& -> \& (which makes the forward & a regular character instead of a delimiter)

Three of them: The first two become one in the shell which then escape the third one in sed
\\\& -> \\&
```

Finally! don't forget that you command is under **backquote**:

The reason you have to escape it "twice" is because you're entering this command in an environment (such as a shell script) that interprets the double-quoted string once. It then gets interpreted again by the subshell.

From:

[Why does sed require 3 backslashes for a regular backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash)

Comment: the double backslashes are single-quoted, so I think it's not necessary to escape it further more, like the first case in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, backquote is the reason.